# Two linear interpolations in the same loop, but one takes longer, why? (Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing two lerps simultaneously, one for centering the camera, other for zooming, using this code:

```
IEnumerator centerCameraAndZoom(Vector2 source, Vector2 target, float duration, float zoomAmount) {

    float t = 0;
    while (t < 1) {

        // add the time
        t += Time.deltaTime / duration;

        // smooth it out (easing)
        var lerped = Mathf.SmoothStep(0.0f, 1.0f, t);

        // zoom in
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = Mathf.Lerp(Camera.main.orthographicSize, zoomAmount, lerped);

        // move canvas center in the direction of the card
        canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = Vector2.Lerp(source, target, lerped);


        yield return null;
    }


}
```

My problem is that, even though both are theorecitally lerping for the same speed (t is the same for both), the motion of the canvas center takes much longer, resulting on a delayed moving after zoom is done.

Any ideas on how to deal with this, while still keeping the code inside of a single loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because each time this loop is executed the camera's orthographic size is used as the "start":

`Mathf.Lerp(Camera.main.orthographicSize, zoomAmount, lerped);`

Let's do a little experimentation, five steps, `0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1` and we'll track the value of the camera's size and the canvas size.

- Step 0 (aka where we start):

  ```
  Camera.orthographic size: 10
  Zoom Amount: 2
  Canvas source size: (10,10)
  Canvas target size: (2,2)
  lerped is 0, so no change is made.
  ```
- Step 0.25:

  ```
  lerped = 0.25
  Camera.orthographicSize (currently 10!)
  Mathf.Lerp(10, 2, 0.25) => 8
  Camera.orthographicSize => 8
  Vector2.Lerp((10,10), (2,2), 0.25) => (8,8)
  ```

  Everything is good so far!
- Step 0.25:

  ```
  lerped = 0.25
  Camera.orthographicSize (currently 8!)
  Mathf.Lerp(8, 2, 0.5) => 5
  Camera.orthographicSize => 5
  Vector2.Lerp((10,10), (2,2), 0.5) => (6,6)
  ```

  Eep! They don't match!

See what happened? Because the camera's *current* orthographic size is used as the "starting point" for the Lerp applied to the camera's orthographic size, it *accelerates* ahead of a true linear interpolation (in the final moments after it looks like it has completed, it is due to having slowed down again, as it's moving "90% of 1 pixel" each frame, but that motion is imperceptible and looks like it has stopped).

You will need to pass the *original zoom* as a parameter to this method and use that, just as you use `Vector2 source` for the canvas.

Comment: Or just make a copy of the `Camera.main.orthographicSize` value outside the `while` loop then use that inside the `while` loop instead `Camera.main.orthographicSize`. That will prevent having to add another unnecessary parameter to the function.

Comment: @Programmer That was actually what I was going to say, then checked the question's code again, and somehow missed the loop and thought "never mind, that wouldn't work."

Comment: Yes, I did that outside the while loop, great answer, thanks a lot guys.